# RSpec 3.2 Model Testing Error in Rails Mountable Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In old RSpec, in a Rails Mountable Engine project with no database underneath. We have the following expectation set up.

```
User.should_receive(:find_by_user_id_and_type).with(42, 'GREAT_USER').and_return(user)
```

The above worked fine.

In rspec 3.2, we changed to

```
allow(User).to receive(:find_by_user_id_and_type).with(42, 'GREAT_USER').and_return(user)
```

This now fails with the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
```

Again the project is a Rails Mountable Engine project and the database lives in the other project that uses this project as a library.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How `User` is defined?